# Parsley remote This value seems to be invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I feel like i have tried every option out there but with no luck

I simply cannot seem to get the response right that will allow me to validate a single input field (username) using ajax with Parsley

Here are the three attempts ive tried without any luck what so ever:

**1 attempt**

Html:

```
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="username"
               data-parsley-remote-validator="remote-email"
               data-parsley-trigger="change"
               data-parsley-remote-validator="reverse"
               data-parsley-remote="/User/user_exists">
```

Javascript:

```
window.ParsleyExtend.asyncValidators['remote-email'] = function (xhr) { return xhr.status === 404; };
```

testet json responses:

```
print 404;
print 200;
print json_encode(404);
print json_encode("404");
print json_encode(200);
print json_encode("200");
```

**2. attempt**

Login.js:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#form_login').parsley();

    $('[name="username"]').parsley()
        .addAsyncValidator('remote-email', function (xhr) {
            return 404 === xhr.status;
        }, '/User/user_exists',
        { "type": "POST", "dataType": "jsonp", "data": { 'request': 'ajax' } }
    );
});
```

html:

```
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="username"
               data-parsley-remote-validator="remote-email"
               data-parsley-trigger="change">
```

the first attempt is the one that gave me the best result however no matter what i did it always says: `This value seems to be invalid.`

Can anyone please point me in the right direction! ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change default message, add an attribute to your input:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="username" data-parsley-remote data-parsley-remote-message = 'your message' data-parsley-remote-validator="remote-email" data-parsley-trigger="change">
```

In the url '/User/user_exists' you need to response something like this:

```
// PHP code
if($_POST['request'] == 'ajax'){
    header("HTTP/1.0 200");// Right
}
else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404"); // Wrong
}
```

After you need to check this line:

```
return 200 === xhr.status;
```